# Populating a two-dimensional array from image groups

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image

I have several images, and I need to be able to group and select them by title, and also manipulate them individually.

My images look like this:

```
<img src="1.jpg" title="cat">
<img src="2.jpg" title="cat">
<img src="3.jpg" title="cat">
<img src="1.jpg" title="dog">
<img src="2.jpg" title="dog">
<img src="3.jpg" title="dog">
<img src="1.jpg" title="horse">
<img src="2.jpg" title="horse">
<img src="3.jpg" title="horse">
```

... and so on.

I'm trying to create an array that looks like this:

```
imgArray = [cat[1,2,3], dog[1,2,3], horse[1,2,3]];
```

... where the first array level is the group(title), and within each group is an array of the actual elements with matching titles. I need to be able to do things like this:

```
var imgGroup = imgArray[cat];
doThings(imgGroup)
function doThings(target){
   var pri = target[0], sec = target[1], ter = target[2];
   pri.doThis(); sec.doThat(); ter.doTheotherthing();
});
```

So far I'm doing this:

```
img.each(function(){
   var self = $(this),  title = self.attr('title');
   imgArray.push([title, self]) 
   imgArray = $.unique(imgArray) //remove duplicate titles
});
```

But this is obviously not working and probably for a reason that makes me look stupid :/

Is anyone able to help me with this logic?

Comment: wait, what are you trying to do? create the array or do something with an existing array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the structure you really need is an object (not an array) where you have a property for each type of animal, and the value of each property is an array of numbers:

```
var imgObj = {
   "cat" : [1, 2, 3],
   "dog" : [1, 2, 3],
   "horse" : [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Then you can say:

```
imgObj["cat"]          // give the array [1,2,3]
imgObj["horse"].length // gives 3
imgObj["dog"][0]       // accesses the first value in the dog array
```

Except that the way your code is trying to create and use your array/object it seems you want the sub arrays to hold jQuery objects that themselves contain the individual DOM img elements? Still you'd want an object where the properties are arrays.

You didn't tag your question as jQuery, though from your existing code you seem to be using it, so here's how you could create the above struture from your markup:

```
var imgObj = {};
$("img").each(function() {
   var title = this.title;
   if (!imgObj.hasOwnProperty(title))
       imgObj[title] = [];

   imgObj[title].push($(this));
});
```

You should then be able to call your existing `doThings()` function as follows:

```
doThings(imgObj["cat"]);    // passes just the cat array
```

Comment: The second part of your answer is exactly what I need. I didn't even think to use an object, but I can see how that simplifies things and makes it easier to reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use class names instead of titles? Then you can handle all the 'horse' elements in a group, using getELementsdByClassName or a query that filters the images by class. Use the titles for unique information...